# How to say the following thing?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

If I have a phone number in usage & after some time I no longer does, **how do I then say it with just one verb in active form & without using negation**? So apart from the following way:-

> I no longer use that number.  (no-hence negation)

or

> I stopped using that number. (stop & use-hence 2 verbs)

in what other way, can we say it? Could we say it as:

> I delinked that number from my phone.
>
> I disconnected that number.
>
> I disabled that number.

Or in some other way so that there is 1 verb & with no negation?

Note- The scenario here is not about changing numbers. Its about stopping the use of a number. So

> I changed that number.

doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why do you set rules like "no negation"? Setting rules like this usually produces less useful answers, especially if the most natural way does use two verbs or negation. If there is a reason for the "rule" then state that reason.

Answer (score 0):

This works: 
I disconnected that number.

As does this: 
I deactivated that number.

Disconnected is the more common of the two, though. When you call a number that is no longer in service, the message generally says: "This number has been disconnected."

Comment: In my idiolect I would not use “I disconnected/deactivated that number”. To me this sounds as if I am speaking from the point of view of the telecommunications company not a customer of the company. I’d expect to hear, “I had that number disconnected.” or “I no longer use that number.”

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to remove *any* negative particles:

> That number is now *obsolete*.

Answer (score 0):

That is no longer my number.

is the simplest way to say it.

There is no negative verb there.